# UI clicks hitting game objects below

Tags: unity, gui

I have a canvas with a panel with set width / height inside. The canvas rendermode is set to ScreenSpace Overlay.

My clicks on the panel are falling through and hitting the game objects below triggering their mouse events.

[image]

The little green circle is a Sprite with the following event

```
  public void OnMouseDown() {
        Debug.Log("click");
        Vector3 newPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (this.transform.position);
        newPos.x -= panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2.0f;
        newPos.y -= panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height / 2.0f;

        panel.transform.position = newPos;
  }
```

I've been reading through the docs but I'm missing something... How do I stop my clicks hitting the game objects below the panel?

Comment: Do your UI elements have the `Blocks raycast` checkbox enabled ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133923/prevent-unity-click-go-trough-canvas/133972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [IsPointerOverGameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) to check if the mouse is over a UI element. Something like this:

```
public void OnMouseDown() {
        if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) return;

        Vector3 newPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (this.transform.position);
        newPos.x -= panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width / 2.0f;
        newPos.y -= panel.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height / 2.0f;

        panel.transform.position = newPos;
  }
```

If you use `IsPointerOverGameObject()` without a parameter, it points to the "left mouse button" (`pointerId = -1`); therefore when you use `IsPointerOverGameObject` for touch, you should consider passing a pointerId to it. For example:

```
private static bool IsPointerOverGameObject()
{
    #if !UNITY_EDITOR && (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE)
        const int fingerId = 0;
    #else
        const int fingerId = -1;
    #endif

    return EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(fingerId);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help with that. 

I was having trouble getting my head around the IsPointerOverGameObject() method but to try sum that up - place that function at the top of any code that handles mouse click on any non-UI components, the method will return true whilst over UI components.