# Input while using Input System and Unity UI

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I'm using Input System and Unity UI and the problem I have is a single event (i.e. mouse press) is being sent to both systems. Here are a few interactions to demonstrate the problem.

- Clicking on a UI element also causes the action assigned to left
  click to trigger.
- Typing in a text field also causes the actions
  associated with those keys to trigger

In the docs it discusses this issue ([UI Support](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/manual/UISupport.html)) and gives the following advice.

- All interaction is performed through UI elements. A 2D/3D scene is
  rendered in the background but all interaction is performed through
  UI events (including those such as 'background' clicks on the
  Canvas).
- UI is overlaid over a 2D/3D scene but the UI elements cannot
  be interacted with directly.
- UI is overlaid over a 2D/3D scene but
  there is a clear "mode" switch that determines if interaction is
  picked up by UI or by the game. For example, a first-person game on
  desktop may employ a cursor lock and direct input to the game while
  it is engaged whereas it may leave all interaction to the UI while
  the lock is not engaged

So basically is suggests handling all input through the UI system/Event System and using the InputSystemUIInputModule to map events to certain actions. However that system has limited input options. I would only be able to use Move, Submit, Cancel, etc. Unless there is something I'm missing with the UI input, it would not work since I need input from 15+ actions.

I was looking to see what other options I have, whether it is related to using the UI input system or something else entirely.

Comment: [You can check EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject when handling mouse clicks in other scripts, and abort if it returns true](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/134568/39518). This way your other scripts can selectively ignore clicks on UI objects. If that solves your problem, we can resolve this question as a duplicate of the one in the link. If not, can you edit your question to clarify what you need that's different from this?

Comment: @DMGregory For some reason I thought that wouldn't work with multiple canvases but that doesn't seem to be the case. For text input then I can check if a text field is selected and ignore it. So this can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem! If you find a case this doesn't solve, feel free to edit your question to have it re-opened, or post a new question.